# Javascript IndexOf on an element of an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, comparison

I have a JavaScript Array called arrTemp.

I want to search arrTemp[1] to see if it contains the character '|'

I have tried the following:

```
var arrValue = arrTemp[1].split(",");
if(arrValue.indexOf('|') > -1) {
    alert(arrValue);
}
```

but it says the method indexOf is not supported for this type.

Is there an alternate method I can achieve this??

Comment: What's the value of `arrTemp[1]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split returns an array, so you need to loop through that array.

```
var arrValue = arrTemp[1].split(",");

for(var i = 0; i < arrValue.length; i++){
    if(arrValue[i].indexOf('|') > -1)
    {
       alert(arrValue[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to see if `arrTemp[1]` contains `|` then you don't even need the split:

```
if(arrTemp[1].indexOf('|') > -1) {
    alert(arrValue);
}
```

Or if you want to see if an entry in the split array is *equal* to '|', e.g. in the string `foo,|,bar` as opposed to `foo,x|x,bar` then you can do:

```
var arrValue = arrTemp[1].split(",");
for(var i = 0; i < arrValue.length; i++){
    if(arrValue[i] == '|')
    {
       alert(arrValue[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might need this polyfill, in case of your browser doesn't support indexOf() for arrays:
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: @Boris my answer only does `indexOf` on string, but your comment is a valid separate answer